# Inserting an idle time when looping

Tags: database, excel, vba

I have written a VBA code to generate some database entries based on an excel list: due to the way the database is set up, I need to first generate an URL and then open the URL to generate the online DB entry.

I could loop through the entire list, but I am afraid that launching 50 or even more consecutive instances of IE with this loop will hung the computer. It's worth mentioning that upon manually opening a single URL the DB takes some seconds to display the proper page.

Is there a way to define an idle time at the end of each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `Application.Wait()`? For example, count from 0 to 10 every 5 seconds:

```
Sub main()

For i = 0 To 10
    MsgBox i
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Next i

End Sub
```